# Develop a user-defined function to sort the array in a non-decreasing order

Tags: c

I just learned about pointer and tried the program on the textbook,

"Declare an array of `char` type with size 8, ask the user to input a
string and then assign to the array. Develop a user-defined
function to sort the array in a non-decreasing order. Print the array
before and after sorting in the main function. The function
prototype is given as
`void arr_sort( char * cPtr)`"

I don't know very clear what mistake I have made.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void print(char *a[]);
void arr_sort( char *a[]);
int main()
{
    int i;
    char *array[8];
    printf("Please input a string with size 7:");
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
     scanf("%s",array);
    }
    printf("the array before sorting is");
    print(array);
    arr_sort(array);
    print(array);
    return 0;
}

void arr_sort( char *a[])
{
    int i,j;
    char *temp;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(a[j],a[j+1])>0)
            {
                temp=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
void print(char *a[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        printf("%s ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `char *array[8];` is **definitely not** an array of `char` type and size 8

Comment: `Declare an array of char type with size 8` is **not** `char *array[8]`

Comment: I am not sure if I should answer this. There are lots of problems in this code.

Comment: On reading the code `char *array[8]` could be correct, but not the way it is used. Function is printing an array of strings - although that too is faulty.

Comment: I'd expect `i = 0; i <= 7; i++`. Just one of the issues.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings: *'scanf' : format string `%s` requires an argument of type `char *`, but variadic argument 1 has type `char **`*

Comment: the first problem I see is: `char *array[8];`  is declaring an array of 8 pointers to char.   However, what you really want is `char array[8];` which declares an array of 8 characters

Comment: the next problem I see is the signatures for the sub functions have a parameter like this: `char *a[]`.  Remember that referencing an array name returns the address of the first byte of the array.  so the parameter is the same as: `char **a`.   Definitely not what is needed.  Suggest: `char a[]`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",array);`  1) the pointers in your declared array `a[]` have not been set to point to any memory that the program owns (I.E. missing a call to `malloc()` (or similar) for each entry.  2) the problem description indicates a single string of characters, NOT a series of strings.  3) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value ( not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. 4) when using the '%s' input/format specifier, always include a MAX Characters modifier that is 1 less than the length (cont)

Comment: (cont) of the input buffer, because that format specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input.  Suggest elimination of the `for()` loop and change the call to `scanf()` to:  if( 1 != scanf( "%7s", array ) ) { // handle error then: exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 7.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statement to give the 'magic' number a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: in C, an array index starts at 0 and continues to (number of elements in array -1.  So this statement: `if(strcmp(a[j],a[j+1])>0)` will, on the last iteration, be accessing the NUL byte at the end of the string

Comment: it is a good programming practice to limit the `scope` of variables.  In the posted code, in function: `arr_sort()`, the variables i, j, and temp are visible through the whole function.  the `i` variable only needs to be visible inside the outer `for()` loop, the `j` variable only needs to be visible inside the inner `for()` loop,  the `temp` variable only needs to be visible inside the body of the `if()` code block.  Similar considerations exist for function: `print()` and the variable `i`

Comment: the question states the prototype/signature for function: `arr_sort()` is `void arr_sort( char * cPtr )`   NOT `void arr_sort( char * cPtr[] )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing a quick 'google' for a bubble sort, in C, results in:

```
// where 'n' is the number of entries in the array
// where 'array' is declared as 'int array[n];
for ( int c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++ )
{
    for ( int d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++ )
    {
        if ( array[d] > array[d+1] ) /* For decreasing order use < */
        {
            int temp   = array[d];
            array[d]   = array[d+1];
            array[d+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the limits on the upper bound of the index variables.

in your program you will be using `char` rather than `int` for `temp` and for the declaration of `array[]`

notice there is no need for anything in the `string.h` header file.

notice the limiting of the scope of the local variables `c`, `d`, and `temp`

The comments on your posted question cover the problems in the posted code, so I will not repeat all of them here.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++) {
  scanf("%s",array);
}
```

If you want 8 strings of length 7, you can't scanf them into the array. Your array is an array of pointers as defined here:

```
char *array[8];
```

Which is very different from this:

```
char array[8];
```

The first is an array that stores 8 pointers to strings. The second is an array that stores 8 characters. If you wanted to store a single string, you would do this:

```
char array[8];
printf("Please input a string with size 7: ");
scanf("%s", array);
```

Which is probably what you're used to at this point.

So, an array of pointers is just like a list of little arrows that point to blocks of memory. Your array doesn't store any characters itself, which is why you can't scanf directly into it.

```
int main(void) {
  char *arr[8];
  char new_word[8];

  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    printf("Enter a new word of length 7: ");
    scanf("%s", new_word);
    arr[i] = malloc(strlen(new_word) + 1);
    strcpy(arr[i], new_word);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This program creates two arrays: a pointer array (arr) and a character array (new_word). In the loop, you ask for seven strings of length 7, which is scanf'd into the character array. New memory is set aside for that string with malloc. Then, the string is copied into the block of memory that your first array pointer points to. We increment our array index with the for loop so that now we're using the next pointer, and so on.

It's important to use strcpy and copy the string out of the character array every time, otherwise at the end, you will just have an array of pointers pointing to a single string, new_word.